# Relative Layout inside ScrollView not working...!

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

This is my abc.xml in which I'm using the relative layout as a parent layout inside ScrollView, I've used fillviewport and scrollbar parameters many times but it's not working...

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:scrollbars="none">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/SU_user_detail_parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background">

  <More Components here..../>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is how I'm implementing this...

```
     AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SelectorActivity.this);

     View view = LayoutInflater.from(SelectorActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.abc, null);

     alertBuilder.setView(view);
     AlertDialog d = alertBuilder.create();

     d.show();
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: ScrollView not working...

Comment: Have you tried by implementing this layout in activity, if not kindly do it for debugging purpose...

Comment: What do you mean by not working, the scrolling doesn't work?

Comment: How about using NestedScrollView? ScrollView sometimes not working for  some cases, though I forgot what are they.

Answer (score 2):

Add LinearLayout inside scrollview and put in Relative layout inside of Linearlayout.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/SU_user_detail_parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/custom_background">

<More Components here..../>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: That's not the right solution @sasikumar  Actually I have to keep the relative layout as parent layout..!!